# navigation button doesn't work as what it should

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, push

currently I'm developing a program that have 2layer of table, which the value will be take from JSON,

I've done almost all, but the navigation part hinder me, the program will have a list of data in the 1st view, then when user click (let say) option 1, it'll switch view to the next table with some option A,B,C,etc.

But so far, when I click the option 1, it never switch view.

Although the data inside the table data source are those of the 2nd table.

Oh, I use the push method to switch the view.

```
RootViewController *rvController  = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:NO];
```

I try to use [self.tableview reloadData], to reload the tableview(hoping to have the correct value shown in the table), it never shown.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell whats going wrong. It sounds like your second controller is load loading data for some reason. Or are you trying to use the same controller for both? turn animation on so you can see the second table slide in. Check that the new instance of RootViewController is actually loading data.

Comment: Actually I'm using the same controller for both. I did that, but the 2nd table never slide in, the view is still the 1st table, and I need to slide the table down(where it hid all the 1st table view), then the 2nd table value will show up in the table. As the value for the instance of new RootViewController, yeah, it does load data. I check using NSLOG for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution from a book. I'll share my finding here, hopefully it'll help those who stuck with the same problem as me.

```
DemoAppDelegate *delegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];
```

It works like a charm to me, hopefully it'll help u guys.

Answer (score 0):

give an iboutlet uitableview *somename to tableview.And change the array which you are passing according to your requirement.And then using the tableview name you can reload it.

Comment: Can I like refresh the whole page? Since I realize the navigation bar on top of the table never being refreshed.